# How to turn a string in to a command

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to turn a string in a dictionary into a callable command.

```
binds = {"<Control-n>" : 'Commands.New()'}
for n, b in binds.values():
    root.bind_all(n, b)
```

So I would like to bind everything in the dictionary.

Comment: If you really want to execute a string as python code, you can use `exec`. So for example, `root.bind_all(n, lambda: exec(b))`

Comment: `eval()` and `exec()` are considered harmful and should not be used. For reference: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: Do you have complete control over the contents of the dictionary? Could someone enter something malicious, or stupid even, and delete everything on your hard drive? If so, don't use `eval`.

Comment: @moooeeeep if you use it safely, there is no harm

Comment: @DavidReeve the lambda you've suggested will defer the binding of the `exec()` argument to the time it's called. Which might not be what you wanted to achieve. For reference: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures

Answer (score 4):

Do not store the commands as strings.  There is not really a clean way of converting them back into functions that you can use with `bind_all`.

Instead, you should make the dictionary's values be references to the function objects themselves:

```
binds = {"<Control-n>" : Commands.New}
for n, b in binds.items():
    root.bind_all(n, b)
```

Also, you should be calling `dict.items` (or `dict.iteritems` in Python 2.x) instead of `dict.values`.  The first method will return tuples of key/value pairs which you can unpack as you are doing.  The second method however only returns values.

Comment: It Still Gives Me The Same ErrorTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Pusdo Code\main.py", line 150, in <module>
    Main()
  File "E:\Pusdo Code\main.py", line 110, in Main
    Bind(root)
  File "E:\Pusdo Code\main.py", line 100, in Bind
    for n, b in binds.values():
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Comment: I think you want `blind.items()` not `bind.values()`.

Comment: Well, then we wouldn't need to use a dict.  A list of tuples would suffice.  The current code works just fine (provided all of the commands accept the event object that will be sent to them).  I just forgot to call `.items()` instead of `.values()`.